# Why are my Functions Not Working in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create an app that can:

- Send Keyboard Input
- Send Scroll Events
- Send Mouse Input (upcoming)

I have made the functions and all (except for Mouse Input), but if I call them, but the following problems happen:

- For Keyboard, this error shows up, even though I have placed an integer

  ```
  Exception in Tkinter callback
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\kiwifruit\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
   return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Kiwifruit\Documents\Python\automaton.py", line 40, in spam
   for i in range(count):
  TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
  ```
- For Mouse Scrolling, Nothing Happens

Here is the code:

```py
    from tkinter import Tk, ttk, BooleanVar, IntVar, messagebox, simpledialog
    from plyer import notification as notif
    from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
    from pynput.mouse import Button
    from pynput.mouse import Controller as MouseController

    # Declaring important variables
    root = Tk()
    selector = IntVar()
    keyboard = Controller()
    mouse = MouseController()
    notifEnablr = BooleanVar()
    notifSelector = IntVar()

    # Settings/Configurations for declared variables
    root.geometry("300x350")
    root.title("Automaton")

    # Classes and Functions
    class app:
        def notifEnable():
            userChoice = notifEnablr.get()
            if userChoice == False:
                notifViaDesk["state"] = "disabled"
                notifViaMsg["state"] = "disabled"
            if userChoice == True:
                notifViaDesk["state"] = "active"
                notifViaMsg["state"] = "active"
        class retrieve:
            def integer():
                integer = simpledialog.askinteger("Requesting Integer", "Please Enter an Integer")
            def string():
                string = simpledialog.askstring("Requesting String", "Please enter a String")
            def floatingInt():
                floatInt = simpledialog.askfloat("Requesting Float", "Please enter a Floating Integer")
        class keybrd:
            def spam():
                message = spamEntry.get()
                count = app.retrieve.integer()
                for i in range(count):
                    keyboard.type(message)
                    keyboard.tap(Key.enter)
        class mous:
            def autoScroll():
                number = int(scrollNtry.get())
                mouse.scroll(number, number)
        class notify:
            def desktopNotifs():
                notif.notify(
                    title = "Done!",
                    message = "Spam has finished task and no longer needs your keyboard",
                    app_name = "Automaton by Kiwifruit",
                )
            def msgboxNotifs():
                messagebox.showinfo("Done!", "Spammer has finished task and no longer needs your keyboard")

    # Notification Selector
    notifLabl = ttk.Label(root, text="Notification Options")
    notifChkBox = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Enable Notifications", variable=notifEnablr, onvalue=True, offvalue=False, command=app.notifEnable)
    notifViaDesk = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Notify Via desktop notifications", variable=notifSelector, value=1)
    notifViaMsg = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Notify Via dialog", variable=notifSelector, value=2)

    # Spam
    spamLabl = ttk.Label(root, text="Keyboard Spam Options:")
    spamenLabl = ttk.Label(root, text="Spam message")
    spamEntry = ttk.Entry(root)
    spamGo = ttk.Button(root, text="Start Spam", command=app.keybrd.spam)

    # Scroll
    scrollLabl = ttk.Label(root, text="Mouse Scroll Options:")
    scrollenLabl = ttk.Label(root, text="Amount of scroll")
    scrollNtry = ttk.Entry(root)
    scrollGo = ttk.Button(root, text="Start Scrolling", command=app.mous.autoScroll)

    # Makes sure that the Notif Radiobuttons are disabled
    app.notifEnable()

    # Placing all the widgets in tkinter window
    # Spam
    spamLabl.place(x=0, y=0)
    spamenLabl.place(x=0, y=30)
    spamEntry.place(x=0, y=50)
    spamGo.place(x=20, y=80)

    # Scrolling
    scrollLabl.place(x=150, y=0)
    scrollenLabl.place(x=150, y=30)
    scrollNtry.place(x=150, y=50)
    scrollGo.place(x=150, y=80)

    # Notifications
    notifLabl.place(x=0,y=250)
    notifChkBox.place(x=0, y=275)
    notifViaDesk.place(x=20, y=295)
    notifViaMsg.place(x=20, y=315)



    # Keeps the app running
    root.mainloop()
```

Anybody who knows why the error appears and how to fix it?

Comment: At the end of your `def integer()` function add `return integer`

Comment: Thank you @TheLizzard. My program worked  _too_ well, but I can fix that myself